# How to create setOnClickListener on an array of buttons in Java

Tags: java, arrays, button, handler

I have a dynamic array of buttons and I would like to know how to handle the onclick on every button?I want also user give the number of buttons from an extra setup menu.I try the below code but give wrong results...How I can leave distance 10dp between buttons from java file? how I can use the handleOnClick method ?

```
     LinearLayout ll = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.buttonlayout2);
     LayoutParams lp = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
     lp.bottomMargin=10;

       Button btn[] = new Button[oNumber];
    for (int i=0;i<oNumber;i++){
        btn[i] = new Button(this); // initialize it
        //btn[i].setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
        btn[i].setText(oName[i]);
        btn[i].setTextColor(Color.rgb(255 , 00 , 00));
        btn[i].setId(i);

      btn[i].setTag(Integer.valueOf(i));

        // btn[i].setOnClickListener(handleOnClick(btn[i]));

        // btn[i].setOnClickListener(this);

        ll.addView(btn[i],lp);
    }

    for( int i = 0; i< btn.length; i++){
        btn[i].setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v){
                //do something

                 //if(v.getId()==0)

                Integer mp=((Integer) v.getTag()).intValue();


                 if( mp==0)  

                 {
                      //its Button 1  do what ever u want

                     Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Extra button 0...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                  }
                 if(mp==1)
                 {
                      //its Button 2  do what ever u want its Button 2


                 Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Extra button 1...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }

            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: You can use setTag() and getTag() instead of id.

Comment: id isn't just any int you want, it is a resource in R file, that's why I recommended using tag instead.

Comment: Can you give me some code about v.getTag ? How I can use it?

Answer (score 0):

Switch the line:

```
btn[i].setId(i);
```

with:

```
btn[i].setTag(Integer.valueOf(i));
```

Also switch:

```
v.getId()==1
```

with:

```
((Integer)v.getTag()).intValue()==1
```

For the margin you need to call requestLayout() after setMargins().

Comment: I test it...the same wrong results...not changes...When I press the first button give me 0 and 1 both toast messages...

Comment: @user2342687 Did you notice the above comment about the first tag being zero?

Comment: Yes...I updated and my code...I think needs different method...HandleOnClick maybe?

Comment: What results do you get? Maybe there is more code that you can show to help understand?

Comment: That's because the second Toast is created out of the 'if' scope.

Comment: Thank you very much!!!Stupid mistake.Can you help me about distance betwwen buttons? The bottomMargin=10; does not works...

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/49503/discussion-between-meir-shapiro-and-user2342687)

Comment: @user2342687 please accept my answer as it seems to have helped you. Thanks.

Comment: @user2342687 For the margin you need to call requestLayout() after setMargins().